# Jquery: change background color of zebra striped divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list of of divs which are zebra striped in css (the odd divs have a light grey background). When clicked, I would like the div's background to change to blue. The below code only works when I click on an even div, presumably because the zebra striping has a higher specificity than the class I add with `addClass`. Swapping the order of the `div.row` and `selected_row` selectors within my css file makes no difference.

```
div.row div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.selectedRow {
    background-color: #338FFF;
}

$('.js-div').on('click', function (e) {
  $(e.toElement).addClass('selected_color');
}
```

Comment: Post the HTML as well.

Comment: Try .selectedRow {background-color: #338FFF !important;}

Comment: Have you tried !important directive on CSS or to .removeClass("row").addClass("selectedRow");

Comment: I can't use !important (because of design standards). Maybe it's just not possible to do the zebra striping with the nth-child selector? (I can just do it in php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply have a more specific `.selectedRow` for the odd ones in your css, too:

```
.selectedRow,
div.row div.selectedRow:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #338FFF;
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/jh602sxk/1/

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the wrong class within the click function. Also, the reason that it's only applying to even rows is because the nth-child(odd) stylings are overriding the class selectedRow.

```js
$('.js-div').click(function(e) {
  if(!$(this).hasClass('selectedRow')) {
      $(this).addClass('selectedRow')
      $(this).css('background-color', '#338FFF');
  } else {
      $(this).removeClass('selectedRow')
      $(this).removeAttr('style');
  }
})
```

```css
.js-div {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}

div.row div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.selectedRow {
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="js-div"></div>
    <div class="js-div"></div>
    <div class="js-div"></div>
    <div class="js-div"></div>
    <div class="js-div"></div>
    <div class="js-div"></div>
    <div class="js-div"></div>
    <div class="js-div"></div>
    <div class="js-div"></div>
    <div class="js-div"></div>
</div>
```

edit:
Added in an alternative way since !important can't be used.